# Hide new pages from current nav by default

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, navigation, pages

In SharePoint 2013, our Site Settings > Navigation Settings are set to "Show Pages" under Current Navigation. We want some pages showing in the navigation and not others. So, we have some pages set to Hidden under "Structural Navigation". This works fine.

We would like it so that when we add a new page to a site it is hidden by default in the Structural Navigation settings. Then, if we want to show it, we would go in to the settings and Show it.

One option would be to not show any pages in the navigation, and instead use the "Add Link" feature to add the pages we want to show in the navigation. We would rather not use links so that if we rename the page or delete it, that it automatically updates in the navigation. We want the pages to stay normal pages in the navigation, but hidden by default. Can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m afraid that is not possible with the OOB settings in [Navigation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca#ID0EACAAA=2013,_2016).

The current settings only provide the ability to hide them **all at once**, or **one by one**.

Maybe you should seek solutions from custom code, if that’s something you are familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Site Pages, the link in the navigation is actually updated automatically if you rename the page. And if you delete it, it disappears. I tested it just now.
But this doesn't work for publishing pages (the link doesn't get updated and you get an "page not found" if you rename it).